# Cone image refinement

Tags: image, math, wolfram-mathematica, geometry

Trying to make a nice three-dimensional graphics of cone intersected by a plane I choose a slight rearrangement of an existing approach in Mathematica (i.e. books by S.Mangano and S.Wagon).  The code beneath is assumed to show so-called Dandelin construction : the inner and outer spheres tangent internally to a cone and also to a plane intersecting the cone. Tangency points of spheres to the plane at the same time are foci of the ellipse.

```
 Block[{r1, r2, m, h1, h2, C1, C2, M, MC1, MC2, T1, T2, cone, slope, plane},
   {r1, r2} = {1.4, 3.4};
    m = Tan[70.*Degree];
    h1 := r1*Sqrt[1 + m^2];
    h2 := r2*Sqrt[1 + m^2];
    C1 := {0, 0, h1};
    C2 := {0, 0, h2};
    M = {0, MC1 + h1};
    MC2 = MC1*(r2/r1);
    MC1 = (r1*(h2 - h1))/(r1 + r2);
    T1 = C1 + r1*{-Sqrt[1 - r1^2/MC1^2], 0, r1/MC1};
    T2 = C2 + r2*{Sqrt[1 - r2^2/MC2^2], 0, -(r2/MC2)};

    cone[m_, h_] := RevolutionPlot3D[{t, m*t}, {t, 0, h/m}, Mesh -> False][[1]];
    slope = (T2[[3]] - T1[[3]])/(T2[[1]] - T1[[1]]);
    plane = ParametricPlot3D[{t, u, slope*t + M[[2]]}, {t, -2*m, 12/m}, {u, -3, 3},
                              Boxed -> False, Axes -> False][[1]];
    Graphics3D[{{Gray, Opacity[0.39], cone[m, 1.2*(h2 + r2)]},
                {Opacity[0.5], Sphere[C1, r1], Sphere[C2, r2]},
                {LightBlue, Opacity[0.6], plane},
                 PointSize[0.0175], Point[T1], Point[T2]},
                 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
                 ViewPoint -> {-1.8, -2.5, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 950]]
```

Here is the graphics : 
 [image: Dandelin construction]

The problem is with the white spots around the both spheres near tangency points. Putting the above code to `Manipulate[...GrayLevel[z]...{z,0,1} ]` we can easliy "remove" the spots as z tends to 1.

1. Can anyone see a different approach to removing the white spots ?  I prefer  `GrayLevel[z]` with z < 0.5.
2. I have been intrigued with a slightly different pattern of the spots on the lower and upper spheres on the graphics . Have you got any ideas how this could be explained ?

Comment: +1 for the nice graphic (even if it does have "white spots")! Some of that old mathematics on conic sections is really beautiful, including the Dandelin construction in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why has no one suggested to just use the built-in `Cone[]` primitive?

```
cone[m_, h_] := {EdgeForm[], Cone[{{0, 0, h}, {0, 0, 0}}, h/m]};
```

This works fine here (no white spots).  Also, it's not a hack or workaround.  The purpose of the empty `EdgeForm[]` is to remove the black outline of the cone base.

[image]

<sub>I just realized that `Cone[]` has a solid base, also very visible on the included image.  So this is not *exactly* the same as the original `RevolutionPlot` version.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

You could construct the cone using a `Tube` with varying radii:

```
cone[m_, h_] := {CapForm[None], Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, {0, h/m}]};
```

Comment: Would someone please explain how this works?  The intersection appears to not be based on the rendered polygons.

Comment: Nice one. I was not aware of this variation of `Tube`. It was tucked away in the "More information" part of its doc page.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to make the spheres a tiny bit smaller:

```
Sphere[C1, .98 r1], Sphere[C2, .98 r2]
```

It's a hack, but it avoids the intersection problem.

Alternatively, you can up the PlotPoints on the cone:

```
PlotPoints -> 100
```

but that will make the rendering slower.

Edit: Or a combination of these to help with speed and quality.

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 60` is sufficient on my machine, and only doubles the amount of time to render.

Comment: @Arnoud, Thanks !  Setting `Sphere[C1, .985 r1], Sphere[C2, .985 r2]` and `PlotPoints -> 100` there remain hardly visible white points, but with `Sphere[C1, .98 r1], Sphere[C2, .98 r2]` I need no additional `PlotPoints` options.