# Graphics3D refinement for intersection of cone and line

Tags: image, wolfram-mathematica

Encouraged by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235778/cone-image-refinement), I dare to ask something similar.

I am trying to plot with mathematica a cone which is intersected by a line. The start point of the line is on the lateral surface of the cone and its endpoint inside of the cone.
As long as the endpoint of the line is far away from the tip of the cone, everything looks quite nice (use e.g. endpointOfLine = 0.007 in my example). But if the endpoint approaches the tip (endpointOfLine < 0.007 in my example), it seems that a big part of the line would be on the surface of the cone.
Sure, for endpoint values which are very close to the cone tip, the line is almost parallel to the surface so that this effect has probably to appear. But the effect appears also if the endpoint is not so close to cone tip.

Here the example:

```
totalLength = 10^-2;(*length of the cone*)
theta = 17*10^-3;(*half opening angle of the cone*)
radius[theta_, l_] := Tan[theta]*l;(*radius of the cone as function of its length*)
endpointOfLine = 0.0015;(*endpoint of the test line, to be varied*)

testLine = Line[{{radius[theta, totalLength], 0, totalLength},{0, 0, endpointOfLine}}, 
                VertexColors -> {Orange, Orange}
           ];
Graphics3D[
  {
     {
       RevolutionPlot3D[{radius[theta, l], 0, l}, {l, 0, totalLength}, 
             Mesh -> None, 
             PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Gray], 
             PlotPoints -> 60][[1]]
     }, 
     {testLine}
  }, 
  Boxed -> True,BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3}, 
  Lighting -> None(*ugly, but makes the problem well visible*)
]
```

[image: ConeAndLine]

Is there any way to reduce this effect? Increasing the PlotPoints to 60 has reduced the effect a bit, but I would be happy if I could reduce it more. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you're referring to the other question, you should test the solutions suggested there, and tell us the results.  You can shift the line (reducing the base radius), increase the cone radius, use Cone[] or Tube[]

Comment: What I see does not match the picture above.  Mathematica 7, Windows 7, ATI graphics.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I can see it (M8/Win7/NVidia). It is slightly dependent on orientation, but if I rotate it as shown the part close to the base gets some sunlight.

Comment: It's best to post these examples complete with `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical`, for easy comparison without manual rotation

Comment: Sorry for not giving ViewPoint and ViewVertical, I wanted the users to see that the problem is a bit dependent on orientation. 
As mentioned in my other comment, I can’t accept as solution to change the cone radius because the graphic has to be precise (if the endpoint is set to 0, the line has to be on the cone). So I have tried to increase the number of PlotPoints and to give the command `PerformanceGoal→"Quality"`. The first improved the problem just a bit.
Unfortunately I am running out of ideas...

Answer (score 1):

Try to place the endpoint at the base of the cone close but not on the radius like:

```
testLine = 
  Line[{{0.97 radius[theta, totalLength], 0, totalLength}, {0, 0, endpointOfLine}}, 
      VertexColors -> {Orange, Orange}
  ];
```

[image]

I feel this is not a problem fundamentally different from the one you were referring to.

Comment: I am sorry, I can’t accept this answer because changing the cone radius etc. is cheating in my opinion. My start point of the line has to be on the surface of the cone because I have to make a precise graphic! If I use your suggestion and set the endpoint of the line to e.g. 0, then the line wouldn’t be any longer on the surface (but in this case it has to be on the surface). Since I have to plot several lines with several endpoints (also enpoint 0) in one graphic, everybody would then recognize that I am doing something wrong with the plot (that I am cheating).

Comment: @partial81 I'm not setting it at 0, I'm setting it at slightly less than one radius distance, in that way preventing numerical inaccuracies in rendering to be visible.  This small offset is hardly visible, if at all.

Comment: I fear you have misunderstood me. I was speaking of the endpoint, not the start point! Try to use `testLine=Line[{{0.97radius[theta,totalLength],0,totalLength},{0,0,0}},VertexColors→{Orange,Orange}];` and you will see that this line is not on the cone (although the start point is slightly less than one radius distance).